# CSS border wrap submenu and parent tab.

Tags: css, css-position

I have a CSS menu with submenu. At the top level, there is a border for top, left, and right. For the submenu, there is a border on all 4 sides. See the JSFiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/vjy8adff/.

I want to move the submenu up by 1px to create an effect that there is only one loop around the parent tab and submenu. Since my submenu is now "absolute" positioned, I can't do the following:

```
ul  ul{
     top: -1px; 
}
```

What is the best solution here.

Comment: `top:calc(100% - 1px);`

Answer (score 1):

At line 17 add :

```
 margin-top: -1px;
```

Full code :

```
ul.menu > li > ul {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -1px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px; 
}
```

Comment: It works in IE, but in Chrome I see a lighter color overlap border. See the fiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/xxe9e8ej/. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you set top to `-1px` the element will calculate the `top` right from the `top` i have set the `top` to `100%` which will bring the element down to `100%` and removed `1px` from it which is the `border`

```
top:calc(100% - 1px);
```

so that it takes the element to `100%` below and exclude `1px border`

you can also use [@ianis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2261599/ianis) solution where the element is moved `1px` `top` with `-ve margin` it acts like `position:relative` with `-ve` `top` value

```css
ul.no-style {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.no-style li {
  padding: 0;
}
ul.list-inline > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* basic menu structure */

ul.menu > li {
  padding-right: 15px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
}
ul.menu > li > ul {
  width: auto;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
ul.menu > li > div.multi-2col {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid #eee 1px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
ul.menu > li > div.multi-2col div.multi-2a {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
ul.menu > li > div.multi-2col div.multi-2a,
ul.menu > li > div.multi-2col div.multi-2b {
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
ul.menu > li > div.multi-2col.right {
  right: 0;
}
ul.menu > li > div.multi-2col.right .multi-2a {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
ul.menu > li > div.multi-2col.right .multi-2a,
ul.menu > li > div.multi-2col.right .multi-2b {
  width: auto;
  float: right;
}
ul.menu > li:last-child {
  padding-right: 0px;
}
ul.menu > li:hover ul,
ul.menu > li:hover div.multi-2col {
  display: block;
}
/* border wrap submenu and parent */

ul.menu.border-wrap > li {
  padding: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
}
ul.menu.border-wrap > li > a {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #eee;
}
ul.menu.border-wrap > li:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-top: solid red 1px;
  border-left: solid red 1px;
  border-right: solid red 1px;
}
ul.menu.border-wrap > li:hover a {
  z-index: 5;
}
ul.menu.border-wrap > li:hover > ul,
ul.menu.border-wrap > li:hover > div.multi-2col {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: solid red 1px;
  left: -1px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul class="no-style list-inline menu border-wrap">
  <li>
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <ul class="no-style">
      <li>Sub Item</li>
      <li>Sub Item</li>
      <li>Sub Item</li>
      <li>Sub Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: For the second solution, it works in IE, but in Chrome I see a lighter color overlap border. See the fiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/xxe9e8ej/. Thanks!

Comment: It's also strange that if I run the code snippet, I won't see the problem, is this problem related to doctype?

Comment: might be try changing it